# Multiply a matrix' columns by its columns

Tags: r, matrix, vector, matrix-multiplication

I have a 4x100 matrix where I would like to multiply column 1 with row 1 in its transpose etc and store these matrices somewhere to be able to take the sum of these new matrices lateron.

I really don't know where to start due to the fact that I get 4x4 matrices after the column-row-multiplication. Due to this fact I cannot store them in a matrix

data:

```
mm num[1:4,1:100]

mm_t num[1:100,1:4]
```

I'm thinking of creating a list in some way

```
list1=list()
for(i in 1:100){
    list1[i] <- mm[,i]%*%mm_t[i,]
}
```

but I need some more indices i think because this just leaves me with a number in each argument..

Comment: Please share your data using valid R syntax.

Comment: The data is a result from previous functions and for loops but i think it would be too confusing if I would copy the whole code since it is a statistic project I'm working with and doesn't really have something to do with this code problem, so I just left you with my data output, from the environment in R stating what my data look like

Comment: I've edited my question because i think the previous wasn't clear. I want to multiply column 1 in the mm matrix (4x1 vector) with row 1 in its transpose mm_t (1x4 vector) which should leave me with 100 4x4 matrices

Comment: Think how it could have been clear from the start (and still clearer than now) if you had shared a small example with sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with some sample data. Please get in the habit of including things like this in your question:

```
nr = 4
nc = 100
set.seed(47)
mm = matrix(runif(nr * nc), nrow = nr)
```

Here's a working answer, very similar to your attempt:

```
result = list()
for (i in 1:ncol(mm)) result[[i]] = mm[, i] %*% t(mm[, i])
result[1:2]
# [[1]]
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.9544547 0.3653018 0.7439585 0.8035430
# [2,] 0.3653018 0.1398132 0.2847378 0.3075428
# [3,] 0.7439585 0.2847378 0.5798853 0.6263290
# [4,] 0.8035430 0.3075428 0.6263290 0.6764924
# 
# [[2]]
#           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
# [1,] 0.3289532 0.3965557 0.2231443 0.2689613
# [2,] 0.3965557 0.4780511 0.2690022 0.3242351
# [3,] 0.2231443 0.2690022 0.1513691 0.1824490
# [4,] 0.2689613 0.3242351 0.1824490 0.2199103
```

As to why yours didn't work, we can experiment and see that indeed we get a number rather than a matrix. The reason is that when you subset a single row or column of a matrix, the dimensions are "dropped" and it is coerced to a plain vector. And when you matrix multiply two vectors, you get their dot product.

```
mmt = t(mm)
mm[, 1] %*% mmt[1, ]
#          [,1]
# [1,] 2.350646
dim(mm[, 1])
# NULL
dim(mmt[1, ])
# NULL
```

We can avoid this by specifying `drop = FALSE` in the subset code

```
dim(mmt[1, , drop = FALSE])
# [1] 1 4
```

And thus slightly modify your attempt, just adding `drop = FALSE` will make it work.

```
res2 = list()
for (i in 1:ncol(mm)) res2[[i]] = mm[, i] %*% mmt[i, , drop = FALSE]
identical(result, res2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I had no idea that the dimensions are dropped when you subset a row/column of a matrix, but that information will come in handy in the future

Answer (score 1):

First, your call for data is not clear. Second, are you tryign to multiply each value by itself, or do matrix multiplication

We create a 4x100 matrix and its transpose:

```
mm <- matrix(1:400, nrow = 4, ncol = 100)
mm.t <- t(mm)
```

Then we can do the matrix multiplication (which is what you did, and you get a 4 x 4 matrix from the definition of matrix multiplication https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Matrix_multiplication)

If we want to multiply each index by itself (so mm[1,1] by mm [1,1]) then:

```
mm * mm
```

This will result in 4x100 matrix where each value is the square of the original value.

If we want the matrix multiplication of each column with itself, then:

```
sapply(1:100, function(x) {
  mm[, x] %*% mm[, x]
})
```

This results in 100 values: each one is the matrix product of a 4x1 vector with itself.

Comment: My call for data is in another chunk, so mm and mm_t is taken from the environment in R just to give you an idea what I'm working with.

I'm afraid that your sapply function doesn't leave me with what i want. The sapply just gives me 100 values, not 100 4x4 matrices which should be the output if i want to multiply one 4x1 vector from mm and a 1x4 vector from its transpose mm_t

Comment: I've edited my question because i think the previous wasn't clear. I want to multiply column 1 in the mm matrix (4x1 vector) with row 1 in its transpose mm_t (1x4 vector) which should leave me with 100 4x4 matrices